# Getting a padding exception in javax.crypto

Tags: java, cryptography, bouncycastle

I'm trying to code a crypto java testclass which encrypt and decrypt a String password with BouncyCastle. The `main()` is very simple, I do `encryptPass()` and then `decryptPass()`, and I watch the console trace.

The problem is when it tries to decrypt, I got a padding exception :

```
javax.crypto.BadPaddingException: pad block corrupted
    at org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.JCEBlockCipher.engineDoFinal(Unknown Source)
    at javax.crypto.Cipher.doFinal(DashoA13*..)
    at com.kiengi.crypto.Crypto.decryptPass(Crypto.java:79)
```

My code is the following for the Crypto class :

```
// password to be crypted
public String pass = "password_go_here";

// key for encrypt pass
public String passKey = generateRandomKey(); // generation clef 16 caractere [a-zA-Z0-9]

// Encrypted pass
public String cryptedPass;

public final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(this.getClass());

private final static byte[] IV_BYTES = new byte[] { 0x07, 0x06, 0x05, 0x04, 0x03, 0x02, 0x01,
        0x00, 0x07, 0x06, 0x05, 0x04, 0x03, 0x02, 0x01, 0x00 };

public Crypto() {
    super();
}

public void encryptPass(){

    Security.addProvider(new BouncyCastleProvider());
    IvParameterSpec _ivSpec = new IvParameterSpec(IV_BYTES);

    try{
        KeyGenerator _keygen = KeyGenerator.getInstance("AES");
        _keygen.init(new SecureRandom(passKey.getBytes()));
        SecretKey _key = _keygen.generateKey();
        logger.trace("Secret key generated");

        Cipher _cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS7Padding", "BC");
        _cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, _key, _ivSpec);

        cryptedPass = asHex(_cipher.doFinal(pass.getBytes("UTF-8")));


        logger.trace("Encrypted pass : "+cryptedPass);


    }catch (Exception e) {
        logger.warn("encrypt failed");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public void decryptPass() {
    byte[] _passKey = passKey.getBytes();
    byte[] _cryptedPass = hexFromString(cryptedPass);

    Security.addProvider(new BouncyCastleProvider());   
    IvParameterSpec _ivSpec = new IvParameterSpec(IV_BYTES);

    try {           
        KeyGenerator _keygen = KeyGenerator.getInstance("AES");
        _keygen.init(new SecureRandom(_passKey));
        SecretKey _key = _keygen.generateKey();
        logger.trace("Secret key generated");

        Cipher _cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS7Padding", "BC");
        _cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, _key, _ivSpec);

        String _pass = new String(_cipher.doFinal(_cryptedPass), "UTF-8");

        logger.trace("Decrypted pass : "+_pass);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        logger.warn("decrypt failed");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}

private int fromDigit(char ch) {
    if ((ch >= '0') && (ch <= '9')) {
        return ch - '0';
    } else if ((ch >= 'A') && (ch <= 'F')) {
        return ch + 10 - 'A';
    } else if ((ch >= 'a') && (ch <= 'f')) {
        return ch + 10 - 'a';
    } else {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException(String.format(
                "Invalid hex character 0x%04x", 0xff & ch));
    }
}

private byte[] hexFromString(String hex) {
    final byte[] buf = new byte[hex.length() / 2];
    for (int i = 0, j = 0; i < hex.length(); i += 2) {
        buf[j++] = (byte) (fromDigit(hex.charAt(i)) << 4 | fromDigit(hex
                .charAt(i + 1)));
    }
    return buf;
}

private static String asHex(byte buf[]) {
    final Formatter formatter = new Formatter(new StringBuffer());
    for (int i = 0; i < buf.length; i++) {
        formatter.format("%02x", 0xff & buf[i]);
    }
    return formatter.toString();
}

private String generateRandomKey() {
    String _chars = "abcdefABCDEF1234567890";
    StringBuffer _pass = new StringBuffer();
    for (int x = 0; x < 32; x++) {
        int i = (int) Math.floor(Math.random() * (_chars.length() - 1));
        _pass.append(_chars.charAt(i));
    }
    return _pass.toString();
}
```

Does anyone knows what this exception means?

Answer (score 0):

This code has a bug. It assumes that `new SecureRandom(passKey.getBytes())` will initialize the SecureRandom instance with *only* the bytes supplied in the constructor. This is wrong. The data in the constructor will *supplement* whatever entropy sources SecureRandom uses, *not replace* them.

You need to use a proper password-based encryption (PBE) scheme.

Comment: Good catch. Yes, you need to hash the password to a key length that will work well with your encryption algorithm (ie use SHA256(password) as an AES 256 key). Currently, you are randomly generating keys for both encryption and decryption.

Answer (score 0):

This exception means that padding block is corrupted. You use PKCS#7 padding with 16B blocks. In this sample your output is 16B too. So it always should be added block with 16 bytes of value 0x10. 
**The padding is corrupted because the decryption is corrupted.** Your SecureRandom implementation adds its own entropy and generates wrong decryption key. This SecureRandom constructor uses the first PRNG algorithm of the first provider that has registered a SecureRandom implementation.